# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'score' not found

Tags: r

We have always been an SPSS shop but we're trying to learn R.  Been doing some basics.  I am trying to do a simple t-test, just to learn that code.

Here's my code, and what's happening:

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QrTf.png)

I don't get why it says "score" isn't found.  It's in the table, and the read.csv code defaults to assuming the first row contains headers. I can't see why it's not "finding" the column for score.  I'm sure it's something simple, but would appreciate any help.

Comment: please do not post code as picture, instead include a minimal data and code as text so that it is reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You didn't store your imported csv file in a variable. It printed to the console because it had nowhere else to go - it just gets printed and then thrown away. You need to assign it for it to be saved in memory:

```
my_data_frame <- read.csv("ttest.csv")
```

Now your data exists in the variable `my_data_frame` and you can use it by supplying it as the `data` argument:

```
t.test(score ~ class, mu=0, alt="two.sided", conf=0.95, var.eg=F, paired=F, data=my_data_frame)
```

Also, in general, I would recommend using `read_csv` from the package `readr` over the default `read.csv` - it's faster.

Finally, when you ask questions, please provide your code as text, not a picture. You should also provide your data or a toy dataset - you can use the function `dput` to print code that will create your data, or just provide the csv file or some code that creates toy data.